# Structure of tabs and tables in Angular 2 - the proper way of doing this

Tags: angular

I have a question related to Angular 2 communication between components. Lets say I have a PageComponent template where I have dynamically loaded tabs (in this example there are static). In these tabs I want to put data which are dynamically loaded in PageComponent using DataLoaderService.

In more simple language: DB data is loaded in PageComponent. PageComponent should fill **tabs** array with **Tab** objects. So, how to pass data from PageComponent to TabsComponent and generate tabs dynamically?

**PageComponent** which is very simple for now. It injects a DataLoaderService which is responsible for collecting data from database. Simple.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataLoaderService } from '../services/data-loader.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/page.template.html',
    providers: [DataLoaderService]
})
export class PageComponent { 
   constructor(private dataLoaderService: DataLoaderService){}
}
```

In **page.template.html** file I have tabs (bootstrap tabs):

```
<tabs>
    <tab tabTitle="Tab 1">
       Here's some content.
    </tab>
    <tab tabTitle="Tab 2">
       And here's more in another tab.
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

And **TabsComponent** and **Tab** code:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

/**
* Tabs Component
*/
@Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
    template: `
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)"   [class.active]="tab.active">
            <a>{{tab.tabTitle}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    `,
})
export class TabsComponent {
    tabs: Tab[] = [];

    selectTab(tab: Tab) {
        this.tabs.forEach((tab) => {
            tab.active = false;
        });
        tab.active = true;
    }

    addTab(tab: Tab) {
        if (this.tabs.length === 0) {
            tab.active = true;
        }
        this.tabs.push(tab);
    }
}

/**
* Tab Component
*/
@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    template: `
    <div [hidden]="!active">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    `
})
export class Tab {
    @Input() tabTitle: string;
    active:boolean = false;

    constructor(tabs:TabsComponent) {
        tabs.addTab(this);
    }
}
```